# Why does Zend mark a subpage as in-active?

Tags: model-view-controller, zend-framework, zend-navigation

I'm having issues setting up my breadcrumbs and menu using Zend_Navigation.

First I set up my pages using a XML config object:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configdata>
<nav>
    <home>
        <label>Home</label>
        <controller>Index</controller>
        <action>index</action>
        <id>home</id>
        <resource>default</resource>
    </home>
    <crm>
        <label>CRM</label>
        <module>Crm</module>
        <controller>Index</controller>
        <action>index</action>
        <id>crm</id>
        <resource>Crm</resource>
        <pages>
            <persons>
                <module>Crm</module>
                <label>Personen</label>
                <controller>Persons</controller>
                <action>index</action>
            </persons>
           (...)etc.(...)
```

Then in my bootstrap:

```
//Bootstrap.php
$view = $layout -> getView();
$config = new Zend_Config_Xml(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/navigation.xml', 'nav');
$navigation = new Zend_Navigation($config);
$view -> navigation($navigation);
$view -> menu = $view -> navigation() -> menu();
$view -> breadcrumbs = $view -> navigation()->breadcrumbs()->setMinDepth(0);
```

Now if I was to navigate to `http://hostname/Crm/Persons/` the active state would work and the breadcrumbs would also display correctly.

However when I go to `http://hostname/Crm/Persons/inspect/id/3` (where inspect is the action and id is a parameter) the breadcrumbs will be empty and none of the menu items will have an active state. The expected breadcrumbs are something like: `Home > CRM > Personen > John` and CRM and Personen should be active in the menu.

Now Zend documentation gave me a clue: it might not be working because of the parameter being set.

```
/*
* Dispatched request:
* - module:     blog
* - controller: post
* - action:     view
*/
$page = new Zend_Navigation_Page_Mvc(array(
    'action'     => 'view',
    'controller' => 'post',
    'module'     => 'blog',
    'params'     => array('id' => null)
));

// returns false, because page requires the id param to be set in the request
$page->isActive(); // returns false
```

I have no idea how to fix this however. Thoughts are highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post your solution as an answer please.

Comment: yes I tried, but SO wouldn't let me :( i'll do it right now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a some (a lot) of tinkering, I figured out I needed to define the page within the XML before Zend would recognize the structure.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configdata>
<nav>
    <home>
        <label>Home</label>
        <controller>Index</controller>
        <action>index</action>
        <id>home</id>
        <resource>default</resource>
    </home>
    <crm>
        <label>CRM</label>
        <module>Crm</module>
        <controller>Index</controller>
        <action>index</action>
        <id>crm</id>
        <resource>Crm</resource>
        <pages>
            <persons>
                <module>Crm</module>
                <label>Personen</label>
                <controller>Persons</controller>
                <action>index</action>
                <pages>
                    <inspect>  <--- this will make Zend recognize the page
                        <module>Crm</module>
                        <label>Persoon</label>
                        <controller>Persons</controller>
                        <action>inspect</action>
                    </inspect>
                </pages>
            </persons>
            (...)etc(...)
```

Note that I didn't want the inspect action to show up on the menu and set the max render depth to 1:

`$view -> menu = $view -> navigation() -> menu()->setMaxDepth(1);`

Comment: This does however require you to set _every_ action, for each controller, as a page in your navigation config file.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used an xml file to set up navigation in ZF before, so I'm not sure this will work. But based on my experiences, add the following to your persons tag:

```
    <params>
        <id>0</id>
    </params>
```

In this example id is set to 0 by default.

See [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123300/passing-url-parameters-to-zend-navigation-using-an-xml-file)

Comment: I'm afraid this does not work (because it will set an ID on the `index` action).