# Zend_Navigation with dynamic URL parameters

Tags: zend-framework, zend-navigation

I'm struggling to implement `Zend_Navigation` breadcrumbs with dynamic URL parameters.

Simple scenario: Imagine a `CompanyController` with a `viewAction()` that takes an `id` parameter from the URL to fetch information about a particular company.

```
URL: example.com/company/view/id/4

Desired breadcrumb: Home > Companies > [ Company name ]
```

I've did some research online and came up with the following solution: in a `predispatch()` hook I take the `id` parameter from `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` (we can't use the request object for this since dispatching hasn't started yet) and fetch that record from the database. Then i simply add this page to its root page in the `Zend_Navigation` container. You can see the implementation of it at the bottom of this post.

The problem i found with this approach is that it's not scalable:

1. What if there's more than one action for each company?

   Apart from `view`ing the company record, we might also want to `edit` (`example.com/company/edit/id/4`) or perform other actions on it. Sure, we could create a switch statement to check the action from the URL, but I feel this is not scalable.
2. What if there's more than one dynamic parameter in the URL?

   For each `company` we also need to manage its `contacts` (the company owner, the financial officer, etc) so we create a `ContactsController` which also holds a `viewAction` and `editAction`. Since a contact is directly tied to a company, we want to have this reflected in the URL and breadcrumbs as well:

   ```
   URL: example.com/company/company-id/4/contacts/contact-id/2

   Desired breadcrumb: Home > Companies > [Company name] > Contacts of [Company name] > [Contact name]
   ```

   We can easily set up a route for this. But now we have to fetch more than one `id` from the URL. This process can get more prone to mistakes as the URL's become more complex.

**So far I've come up with two plausible solutions:**

1. Extend the `Plugin_Navigation::preDispatch()` hook

   A possible solution would be to use verbose URL parameters (like `company-id` and `contact-id`). This way we can extract the name (ie `company`) and fetch the record through the corresponding model class.
2. Add the pages to the navigation container in our action methods

   This would be the most flexible option I think, but it also means that we can't manage our breadcrumbs from a central point anymore, which is a serious downside.

I've done a fair amount of research but there doesn't seem to be an out-of-the-box solution for this problem. Any help would be very much appreciated.

**The `Plugin_Navigation::preDispatch()` hook mentioned earlier:**

```
class Plugin_Navigation extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    public function preDispatch()
    {
        $view       = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getExistingHelper('ViewRenderer')->view;
        $config     = new Zend_Config_Xml(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/navigation.xml','nav');
        $container  = new Zend_Navigation($config);

        $urlParts   = explode('/', ltrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/'));
        $pos        = array_search('id', $urlParts);

        if ($pos !== FALSE)
        {
            $id         = $urlParts[$pos + 1];

            $model      = new Model_Company();
            $company    = $model->fetchOne($id);

            $rootPage   = $container->findOneBy('controller', 'company');

            $rootPage->addPage(new Zend_Navigation_Page_Mvc(array(
                    'controller' => 'company',
                    'action'     => 'view',
                    'label'      => $company->name
                )));

            $view->navigation($container);
        }
    }
}
```

**Some references on this topic:**

- [Zend_Navigation in the ZF Reference Guide](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.navigation.html)
- [Dynamically add pages to Zend_Navigation container at runtime](http://www.evilprofessor.co.uk/236-dynamically-add-pages-to-zend_navigation-container-at-runtime/)
- [Passing url parameters to Zend_Navigation using an XML-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123300/passing-url-parameters-to-zend-navigation-using-an-xml-file)
- [Tips and Trics for Zend_Navigation](http://juriansluiman.nl/en/article/109/tips-and-trics-for-zend_navigation)

Answer (score 0):

You can Solve This Simply By **bootstraping the front controller** in the bootstrap.php file

in bootstrap.php file add:

```
public function _initRequest()
{
    $this->bootstrap('frontController');
    $front = $this->getResource('frontController');
    $front->setRequest(new Zend_Controller_Request_Http());

    $request = $front->getRequest();
}
```

then in the plugin pass the **request object** in the **preDispatch** function :

```
class Your_Controller_Plugin_PluginName extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
     public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
     {
           $MyController =$request->getControllerName();
           $MyAction     =$request->getActionName();
           $MyParams     =$request->getParams(); 

    //now you can go ahead with implementing your breadcrumb

     }
}
```